# Failed to launch browser with \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline

Tags: c#, email, .net-core, gmail, gmail-api

Iam using this code to send email with my web service

```
string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailSend };
string ApplicationName = "SendMail";
UserCredential credential;
            //read credentials file
            using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None
                    ).Result;

            }

            string plainText = $"To: user@domain.io\r\n" +
                               $"Subject: subject\r\n" +
                               "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n" +
                               $"<h1>test email</h1>";

            //call gmail service
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            var newMsg = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message();
            newMsg.Raw = Base64UrlEncode(plainText.ToString());
            service.Users.Messages.Send(newMsg, "me").Execute();
```

it works totally fine locally after deployment it throws this error
`Failed to launch browser with \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline`
even though i added the server url in the redirect uri section and the client's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Considerations

You are using the Installed App Authorization flow in a Web Server. This is not meant to work. You will have to handle authorization differently in a web hosted application.

In code this translates in using `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` instead of `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` to build the Client instance to authenticate and authorize the Google APIs.

### Installed App VS Web Applications

When deploying a Web Application you will have to get the correct type of ClientID first.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) an extensive guide on how to authenticate Web Server Applications.

Although this is very similar in every Client library, [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc) is an example on how to implement the Server Side authentication flow in the .NET Framework.

### References

[OAuth2 For Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server)

[OAuth2 Google Client Libraries .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth)

Comment: In the case of web applications, you need to specify redirect URLs in Dev Console. If an application lacks constant IP address/URL, what would be suggested way for using Google APIs? For example, my application can be launched as localhost/appname or some serveripaddress/appname.