# Google OAuth2 email credentials

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I am writing a Xamarin.Forms (C#) mobile application. It's for a single google spreadsheet  modification, just a few buttons, each one changes a single cell in the spreadsheet. The spreadsheet is private, only several people can read or do any changes, that's why I need to use the `UserCredential credential;` here. I've found two approaches, both throwing different exceptions:

1. `credential = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer{ClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(...).Secrets, Scopes = new[]{...}, DataStore = new FileDataStore(..., true) }), "user", null);`
2. `credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(...).Secrets, new string[]{...}, "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(..., true)).Result;`

The `credential` is later set as member `SheetsService.HttpClientInitializer` of the `service` object, which is used as follows (selected spreadsheet is public, `spreadsheetId` and `range` are taken from the Google's `.Net quickstart`: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet#prerequisites):

```
string spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms", range = "Class Data!A2:E";
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);
var resp = request.Execute();
```

Exceptions:

1. line `var resp = request.Execute();` throws the `System.NullReferenceException` (I found that the property `Credential` in the `Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest` base class is the `null`.
2. the `AuthorizeAsync` method throws an exception with the following message:

> Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&resp…"

P.S.: I've also tried the `GoogleCredential` approach which works fine with the public spreadsheet but my "service" has no permissions to even read this private one...

Comment: This link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64445242/failed-to-launch-browser-with-https-accounts-google-com-o-oauth2-v2-authacc) may help you.

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT : thx for link, but I found no answer there for the Xamarin project (only references to the Google documentations, which I checked at first)

Comment: Is there a problem similar to "redirect uri mismatch"?

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT nope :(
But I've taken a look at the debug-output and there I found the following error(?):


"AOT: image 'Mono.Security.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed"
First step I tried, was adding the "Mono.Security" reference to the Android project (no result), then I also checked the "System.Security" (same),..

Comment: The one you use seems to have stopped updating for two years. Recommend you to use:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?context=xamarin%252Fxamarin-forms&amp%3Btabs=ios&tabs=ios

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT Ok, but how then use the Google.Apis? The WebAuthenticator would be only for Request.HttpContext, correct? Does the P.S. mean anything?

Comment: To check the official documentation example, you can use new Uri();

Comment: Did you get GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync to work with Xamarin?

Comment: @DaImTo - no I've stayed with the 'GoogleCredential', just added the service address to the list of privates that can modify the spreadsheet...

Comment: Nice work around as i know that the library doesnt support xamarin i had to do my own "hack" to get it to work a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern to use a Google client library is to first initialize a *service* object, and then use that object to create requests:

```
new XxxxService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
  HttpClientInitializer = credential
}
```

For Sheets, this should look like:

```
var resource = new SpreadsheetsResource(
  new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
  {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential
  });

resource.Get(...)
```

Comment: Thx, for a post, but that's not an answer for the question, How to "use" the credential is not the problem here (as I wrote in the postscriptum, the ```GoogleCredential``` object works fine).